# flutter: getx RxList not run obx builder

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using getx on my project . I have `RxList` and buy Obx I shows my data on widget:

```
  RxList<VocabularyModel> vocabs = RxList();
```

and widget:

```
   return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Obx(
          () => ListView.builder(
            // ignore: invalid_use_of_protected_member
            itemCount: controller.vocabs.value.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.h, horizontal: 8),
```

In controller I have method to remove on object in vocabs:

```
  void changeToRememberState(int index) {
    final upateItem = vocabs.value[index].copyWith(remember: true);
    vocabs.value.removeAt(index);
    // repository.changeToRememberState(index, upateItem);
  }
```

But when I remove object from vocabs, `Obx` builder not triggered? Why? I remove one element from RxList, Why RxList not fire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Lists** are reactive (Rx) by  default. Therefore if you are using `RxList` or `[].obs` you should not use `.value` to access it. Or I  should say, you should not  **ignore: invalid_use_of_protected_member**. That's why your `Obx` isn't triggering rebuild when you are removing. Because you are removing the underlying List elements and not from the stream.

Unless you use `Rx<List<VocabularyModel>>`, you should not use `vocabs.value`.
Therefore removing `.value` from `vocabs` will fix the rebuild issue.

- Widget:

  ```
  return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Obx(
      () => ListView.builder(
        itemCount: controller.vocabs.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.h, horizontal: 8),
  ```
- Controller:

  ```
  void changeToRememberState(int index) {
     final upateItem = vocabs[index].copyWith(remember: true);
     vocabs.removeAt(index);
    }
  ```

Comment: Thank you ❤️, I was stucked in a loop and wasted 3 days.